# React Native fails to render mutliple chart components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I've run into a long running stumper. I have a chart component in react native. I want to render a series of charts using some apis data. Here is a fragment of the containing elements. The data is being collected and rendered as expected, until it's fed into the chart.

```
<View className={'w-full'}>
  {chartWidgets &&
    chartWidgets.length > 0 &&
    chartWidgets?.map((w: PageWidget<IQuickGraphWidget>, i) => {
      return (
        <View className={'w-full mb-4'} key={i}>
          {w?.widget?.settings?.graph?.split(':')[1] && (
            <ChartWidget
              enabled={true}
              widgetData={w}
              key={i}
              onSelectControl={() => {}}
              pointData={{}}
              graphId={w?.widget?.settings?.graph?.split(':')[1]}
              pos={i}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      );
    })}
</View>
```

below is the chart component. In my test scenario I want to render 3 charts, each charts having an array of on an average 1000 to 2000 points to render. When I get over 2 charts the render of the 3rd or further charts is always broken.

```
/** Vendor */
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Pressable,
  View,
  Text,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import {useQueries, useQuery} from '@tanstack/react-query';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import {RadioGroup} from 'react-native-radio-buttons-group';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import {
  faEllipsisVertical,
  faLineChart,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';

/** Lib */
import {
  someApiEndpoint
} from 'someApiEndpoint';
import {cardShadow} from '../../utils/nativeStyles';

/** State */
import {useStateContext} from '../../stateManager';
import {VictoryLineChart} from './VictoryLineChart';
import {VictoryBarChart} from './VictoryBarChart';

export const ChartWidget: React.FC<any> = ({
  widgetData,
  pointData,
  handleOnSelectControl,
  enabled = true,
  graphId = '',
  inView = false,
  triggerModal = false,
  pos = 0,
}) => {
  /** Variables */
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<any>>();
  const {appState} = useStateContext();

  const defaultEndDate = new Date();
  const defaultStartDate = new Date();

  defaultStartDate.setDate(defaultEndDate.getDate() - 1);

  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(defaultEndDate);

  const timeRangeOptions: any[] = [
    {id: '1', label: '1 Hour', value: 1},
    {id: '2', label: '12 Hours', value: 12},
    {id: '3', label: '1 Day', value: 24},
    {id: '4', label: '1 Week', value: 168},
    {id: '5', label: '1 Month', value: 720},
    {id: '6', label: '1 Year', value: 8760},
  ];

  const [selectedTimeRangeOption, setSelectedTimeRangeOption] = useState('3');
  const [scaleMinValue, setScaleMinValue] = useState('');
  const [scaleMaxValue, setScaleMaxValue] = useState('');
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [modalSettingType, setModalSettingType] = useState('');
  const [initDateRange, setInitDateRange] = useState(false);

  const [chartSettings, setChartSettings] = useState<any | null>(null);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState<any | null>(null);

  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(enabled);
  const [shouldRefetch, setShouldRefetch] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  /** Utils */
  const parseDate = (dt): string => {
    const padL = (nr, len = 2, chr = '0') => `${nr}`.padStart(2, chr);

    const returnString = `${padL(dt.getFullYear())}-${padL(
      dt.getMonth() + 1,
    )}-${dt.getDate()} ${padL(dt.getHours())}:${padL(dt.getMinutes())}:${padL(
      dt.getSeconds(),
    )}`;

    return returnString.trim();
  };

  const getSelectedRangeLabel = () => {
    const option = timeRangeOptions.find(i => i.id === selectedTimeRangeOption);
    return option?.label || '';
  };

  const setDefaultStartDateRangeBySetting = defaultTimePeriod => {
    const defaultStartfromSettings = new Date();
    if (!startDate) {
      if (defaultTimePeriod === 604800) {
        setSelectedTimeRangeOption('4');
        defaultStartfromSettings.setDate(defaultEndDate.getDate() - 7);
      } else {
        defaultStartfromSettings.setDate(defaultEndDate.getDate() - 1);
      }
      setStartDate(defaultStartfromSettings);
      setInitDateRange(true);
      return defaultStartfromSettings;
    }
    setInitDateRange(true);
    return startDate;
  };

  const checkDisableForward = (): boolean => {
    const now = new Date();
    now.setMinutes(0);
    now.setSeconds(0);
    now.setMilliseconds(0);
    return endDate > now;
  };

  const getSettings = async (gId: number) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const settings = await someApiEndpoint(
      appState?.siteId,
      gId,
    );
    setChartSettings(settings);
    getData(graphId, settings);
  };

  const getData = async (gId, settings: any | null = null) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let queryStartDate: Date | null = startDate;
    if (isNaN(parseInt(gId)) || !settings?.web_quick_graph) {
      return null;
    }
    if (settings?.web_quick_graph && !queryStartDate) {
      queryStartDate = setDefaultStartDateRangeBySetting(
        settings.web_quick_graph?.settings?.default_time_period,
      );
    }
    
    const res: any = await someApiEndpoint();
    setChartData(res);
  };

  /** Hooks */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (graphId) {
      getSettings(graphId);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [graphId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initDateRange) {
      getData(graphId, chartSettings);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [startDate, endDate]);

  // refetch when a user preference is changed
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldRefetch) {
      setShouldRefetch(false);

      getSettings(graphId);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [shouldRefetch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showModal) {
      return;
    }

    if (chartSettings) {
      const listSetting =
        chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.settings?.auto_display || false;
      const visible = inView ? true : listSetting;

      setIsVisible(visible);

      if (!visible) {
        return;
      }
    }

    if (!!chartSettings && !!chartData) {
      if (chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.user_scale) {
        setScaleMinValue(
          chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.user_scale?.minimum.toString(),
        );
        setScaleMaxValue(
          chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.user_scale?.maximum.toString(),
        );
      } else if (chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.value_axes) {
        setScaleMinValue(
          chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.value_axes[0].minimum.toString(),
        );
        setScaleMaxValue(
          chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.value_axes[0].maximum.toString(),
        );
      } else {
        let largest = -Infinity;
        let smallest = Infinity;

        for (const item of chartData?.data) {
          if (Array.isArray(item?.g) && item?.g?.length > 0) {
            for (const value of item.g) {
              if (value > largest) {
                largest = value;
              }

              if (value < smallest) {
                smallest = value;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        setScaleMinValue(smallest.toString());
        setScaleMaxValue(largest.toString());
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [chartSettings, chartData]);

  /** Handlers */
  const handleOnCancel = () => {};
  consthandleOnOpenModal = () => {};
  const handleOnSelectOption = val => {};
  const handleOnSetScale = () => {};
  const handleOnTimeline = () => {};
  const handleOnBack = () => {};
  const handleOnForward = () => {};
  const handleOnNavigateToChart = () => {};

  if (!isVisible || !chartSettings || !chartData) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <View
      className="w-full flex flex-1 bg-white"
      style={!inView ? cardShadow : {}}>
      {!inView && (
        <View className="flex flex-row justify-between w-full border-b border-ricado-gray mb-2 p-4">
          <Text className="text-ricado-green text-sm text-left pt-1">
            {widgetData?.widget?.settings?.title}
          </Text>
          <View className="flex flex-row">
            <Pressable onPress={handleOnNavigateToChart} className="mt-2 mr-4">
              <Text>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLineChart} />
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
            <Pressable onPress={handleOnOpenModal} className="mt-2">
              <Text>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsisVertical} />
              </Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}

      <View className={'w-full relative'} style={{minHeight: 300}}>
        {chartData && chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.type === 'line' && (
          <VictoryLineChart
            chartData={chartData}
            chartSettings={chartSettings}
          />
        )}

        {chartData && chartSettings?.web_quick_graph?.type === 'bar' && (
          <VictoryBarChart
            chartData={chartData}
            chartSettings={chartSettings}
          />
        )}
      </View>

      <View className="flex flex-row justify-between w-full border-y border-ricado-gray mt-2 p-4">
        <Pressable onPress={handleOnBack}>
          <Text className="text-black uppercase text-sm">
            {'\u25C0'} Back {getSelectedRangeLabel()}
          </Text>
        </Pressable>
        <Pressable onPress={handleOnForward} disabled={checkDisableForward()}>
          <Text
            className={`${
              checkDisableForward() ? 'text-gray-400' : 'text-black'
            } text-sm uppercase`}>
            Forward {getSelectedRangeLabel()} {'\u25B6'}
          </Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

so far I've tried: victory charts native, victory XL, amcharts5 in a webview, echarts, gifted chartds, multiple component and data fetching refactors (too many to list), useMemo, useRef, useCallback, Staggering renders, reducing data points, etc.

All have the same bug, data rendered fine when printed out there only and issue when rendering more than 2 charts.

Research tells me and issue with reactSVG but in the latest iteration I've swapped to victoryXL which replaces reactSVG with Skia and the problem remains. Have I just missing something simple?

Up to 2 instances of the charts will render but more than that it consistently fails. Not allowed to screenshot the failing render but I mean it draws a couple of gridlines of the chat component is broken including the header and footer which are just simple reactNative elements.

Sometimes they all just bunch up with the mostly rendered charts stacked and the container element just missing.

Often rotating the screen can fix it on a re render. sometimes (but it must re-render first time)

Remove the chart and the rest of the component and the data comes out as expected so I am convinced this is all chart related. No error message is being produced in the console.

Edit: this is a tricky one, assume I've been through a troubleshooting process and have identified the issue and already tried working through it with chatGPT and all the rudimentary things like Memoizing etc. Worth a note as well: the charts don't live update, they pull their data one time.

Comment: I know this is definately not what you are looking for as an answer; but there is a really handy library chart.js (https://www.chartjs.org/) I have used it before, and it does great rendering data. I would say use that instead of natively rendering data in react. If you opt to do it all in react you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Comment: thanks for the uggestion but yeah unfortunately, all the web charts need to go inside a webview for reactNative, and the webview is using react native svg. I think there's and underlying problem with react Native itself, making this a tricky one to solve.

Comment: what is the error message.share the screenshot.

Comment: @Milind frustratingly there is no error message, the first two charts load fine, any after that just don't, logging out the data is fine, the data has been all validated and all works in sets of two max. occasionally the broken ones draw the lines but the rest of the component isn't rendered at all. even if it's just a piece of text. Unfortunately data is too sensitive to provide a screenshot. But hmm is there any way to make repoduction example for react native I wonder...

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same issue. That is not a solution because you can choose many ways. Here some:

1 - navigators don't want play with huge data, no one needs see a thousand of anything, Just a simplified version of that, so simplify presentation with a little part of data should be a good option;

2 - ok, i really need present huge data,
Check out about your server engine configs, you can change How much large your response can be.

3 - Mobile Will priorize performance, so same OS such as Android, can truncate data to improve rendering process, so be aware.

4 - Ok, guys this is a not elegant solution but probably Will fix. Stream data over a long pooling or even better websockets can help handle large data because not received at once, but in small packages.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion. Data size througth the network is not the issue, and the chart solution works just fine in our old Xamarin app with Victory and on every web app product. The charts do not live update. The issue is specific to ReactNative / react-svg and the number of points that need to render.